# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

I have a controller class with a few methods one of which is a method that is supposed to take POST requests.

When I try to send a POST request I get an error that says:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public com.dmall.cx.salecontract.common.entity.CxHttpResult<java.lang.String> com.dmall.cx.salecontract.web.controller.CxContractGoodsController.exceptionResolve(com.dmall.cx.salecontract.service.dto.CxContractGoodsDTO) throws java.lang.Exception
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:157)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The contentType of the POST request is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'.And the form data is:

```
{"id":38,"contractStatus":null,"contractNo":null,"abnormalDesc":"asdf%","abnormalCode":302,"abnormalStatus":1,"scheduleNo":"D6666","supplierCode":"100002","compensateValue":-2,"updateUserId":10000001,"goodsCode":"1063222","createUserId":10000001,"contractType":1,"goodsName":"sdfsdfsdf","discountType":2,"startDate":"2018-09-09","endDate":"2018-09-09","shopCodes":"1024","compensateType":1,"pContractNo":null,"compensateTypeDesc":"zzzz","createTimeDesc":"2019-04-19 11:17:48","abnormal":true,"skuId":null,"changeDesc":"1","isProfitDesc":"0","supplierName":null,"discountTypeDesc":"1","updateUser":"CxUser","createUser":"CxUser","createTime":1555643868000,"updateTime":1555661247000}
```

The `abnormalDesc` attribute contains '%'.If I remove '%', the program perform well,but it won't perform well when the body contains the '%s'.

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding the special characters in your request. `'%'` is one of them.

`%` encoded equivalent is `%25`, so your payload should contain: `"abnormalDesc":"asdf%25"`.

This is needed because your `content-type` is set as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and thus it should be treated as GET parameter strings.

Comment: Is there any general solutions?I can't replace every string attibute in form data.

Comment: before  setting `"abnormalDesc"`  attrubute value, you can encode in javascript as `escape(abnormalDescValue)` and then after getting payload in controller, you can decode its value back in java as `URLDecoder.decode(encodedAbnormalDescValue)`